# find common files in different sub-directories using shell/bash script

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I need to find files in sub-directories and compare the file with the source folder. but I am getting error while using diff command as its checking multiple directories at the same time due to */ .

r="*/"

`for i in QDC RTF`
do
k=`find product/$i/ -type d -printf '%d\n' -name ".git" -prune -o -type f -print | sort -rn | head -1`
array=()
for (( j=0; j < k ; ++j ))
do
`diff -rqs  product/Release/Ticket/ product/$i/${array} | grep "Files"`
array="$array$r"
done
done
$ sh  -x  build.sh

``` ++ find product/RTF/ -type d -printf '%d\n' -name .git -prune -o -type f -print  ``++ sort -rn ```
++ head -1
+ k=5
+ array=()
+ (( j=0 ))
+ (( j < k  ))
+ grep Files
`+ diff -rqs product/Release/Ticket/ product/RTF/`
+ array='*/'

+ (( ++j  ))

+ (( j < k  ))

+ grep Files

`+ diff -rqs product/Release/Ticket/ product/RTF/dev/ product/RTF/v1r7/`
`diff: extra operand 'product/RTF/v1r7/'`
diff: Try 'diff --help' for more information.

+ array='*/*/'

+ (( ++j  ))

+ (( j < k  ))

+ grep Files

``` + diff -rqs product/Release/Ticket/ product/RTF/dev/build/ product/RTF/v1r7/dev/   ``product/RTF/v1r7/dist/ ```
`diff: extra operand 'product/RTF/v1r7/dev/'`
diff: Try 'diff --help' for more information.

+ array='*/*/*/'
+ (( ++j  ))
+ (( j < k  ))
+ grep Files
`+ diff -rqs product/Release/Ticket/ product/RTF/v1r7/dev/build/`
`product/RTF/v1r7/dist/delta/ product/RTF/v1r7/dist/sabre/`
`product/RTF/v1r7/dist/trp/`
`diff: extra operand 'product/RTF/v1r7/dist/delta/'`

Comment: Look at the man-page of diff: _diff [OPTION]... FILES ..... FILES  are  'FILE1  FILE2' or 'DIR1 DIR2' or 'DIR FILE' or 'FILE DIR'.  If --from-file or --to-file is given, there are no restrictions  on  FILE(s)._

Comment: Paste your code in https://www.shellcheck.net/ you will see some syntax errors.  You have to many "`" characters.  This could be related to the editor here, but review your question, it's not possible to help like that.